# 2017 Sentra won't start w/o a jump. Battery only a few months old and mechanic checked out alternator

Tags: battery, nissan, sentra

I started having issues starting the car a week ago. The battery had recently been replaced. Once the car starts (with a battery pack I keep in the car now), it has no issues driving.

I took it to a mechanic today and the battery and alternator look fine, so we're stumped. Any ideas what could be the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Have you checked the voltage at the battery with the engine on/off? If so, what are those voltages? Has the starting issue been happening ever since the new battery (Or even before)? Did you clean the terminals before installation of the new battery?